# How to remove currency full name in magento 2 like USD- US Dollar. i wanna remove US Dollar

Tags: magento2, currency, countries

I am using Magento 2 and I wanna remove the currency country name. I mean just code should be shown.

Thanks

[image: how to remove currency full name in magento 2]

Comment: Did you search the project? Try `grep -rnw vendor/ -e 'us dollar'`, or even better, pick something from the html which is unique to find out where it is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

The string you are looking for in magento 2.3.7 is in the following template at line 34. You just have to change it for whatever you want.

vendor\magento\module-directory\view\frontend\templates\currency.phtml

```
<a href="#" data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getSwitchCurrencyPostData($_code) ?>'><?= $block->escapeHtml($_code) ?> - <?= $block->escapeHtml($_name) ?></a>
```